# Android email send on each admon ad click

Tags: android, eclipse, email

i am VERY new to the Android platform coding, have no skills at all, but know to edit stuffs and add some basic modifications like everyone else so, however im trying to get my app to inform me about how many ppl each click.

I mean, each time when someone clicks on the ad Banner, it should send an anonymous email (without anything special in the mail, just sending it to me).

At the same time during clicking on the ad, it should both send the email without any special message and show the ad page.

I need this to know when people clicked it, because i can't track people who really says they done or not and im uncapable to trace who clicked or not.

as i said, im VERY new, so please be kind to me im not skilled at all.

Comment: I'm not sure but doing operations on ads click may be a policy violation of google play.  For youe question : Your advertiser network will give you each and every detail of your ads even the location So, there is no need to do this.

Comment: Hey, im sorry for late reply, however i got friends that support me and click ads, but i am not sure if they REALLY do, they just say it and the admob statistic update frequency is really slow too, so i cant see them if they click or not. With location, i understand you it gives location, but only Country, no more geo-ip locations. I need just something that gives me a new statistic each 5minute or 1 minute, no matter how long as long as it is not exceding 5minute. Can't anyone give me a simple idea and code to implement? btw, i havent putted in to google playstore, so calm down guys! :) Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

**Using email** to do this work **is a very bad idea**. The answer to your question is "**don't do it this way**".

- it's technically a poor solution - dealing with that large volume of email will likely cause all sorts of problems, both for you and for the people who are installing your app
- sending email surreptitiously on behalf of your clients is considered shady, usually - you're likely to get your app marked as containing malicious code.
- going around existing ad tracking interfaces and apis is often against the agreements you're normally required to sign with ad providers
- the end result is likely to be not useful for you - email, in large quantities, for this kind of stuff, can be less reliable than alternatives

---

Instead, look into creating a service/api, and have the app call the service/api each time an ad is clicked. Most ad providing software provide an interface for hooking into the ads so you can track them.